# Does enabling Dev Hub disable anything else? Can I turn off Dev Hub?

Tags: metadata-api, sandbox, salesforcedx, scratch-org, dev-hub

I am looking at that Dev Hub feature and how well scratch org development mirrors what I do currently in Sandboxes and metadata API deployments.  It'd be nice to pilot the feature, but if it is insufficient for my needs, I'd like to turn it off and (also) to perhaps keep it on and work around it.

Are either of those possible, or must I jump into sfdx with two feet?

Answer (score 7):

As per [Enable the Dev Hub in Your Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm):

> Enabling Dev Hub in a production or business org is completely safe and won’t cause any performance or customer issues. The Dev Hub is comprised of objects with permissions that allow admins to control the level of access available to a user and an org.

and

> After you enable the Dev Hub, you can’t disable it. If you're using a trial org, Dev Hub is already enabled.

So once you turn it on you can't turn it off, but generally there will be no side effects except for a few extra sObjects.

If you aren't certain you want it on indefinitely go with a [30-day Dev Hub Trail org](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/dx-signup) instead.

---

The only caveat I can currently think of is around linking a namespace to the Dev Hub Org - [Link a Namespace to a Dev Hub Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm) (my emphasis):

> Choose namespaces carefully. If you’re trying out this feature or need a namespace for testing purposes, choose a disposable namespace. Don’t choose a namespace that you want to use in the future for a production org or some other real use case. **Once you associate a namespace with an org, you can't change it or reuse it.**

**Update** - I found another area to consider around the second-generation packages - [Best Practices for Second-Generation Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_best_practices.htm):

> - We strongly recommend that you work with only one Dev Hub org, unless you have a strong use case for concurrent use of multiple Dev Hubs.
> - Every second-generation package that you create is owned by a specific Dev Hub. If the Dev Hub org associated with a package expires or is deleted, **its packages no longer work**.

Comment: I know that "completely safe" is in the documentation. I was wondering if anyone had any experience where that was proven wrong.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I haven't encountered any side-effects in turning it on, but that isn't to say that someone else hasn't been caught out. The biggest side effect I could come up with was the permanent connections to a namespace and any second gen packages that get created.

Comment: Do those extra Sobjects cost many storage? We are close to our storage limit at this point.

Comment: I'd need to check the storage usage reports to see if they show up.